# "Actions must be a plain object" redux thunk on react native

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk

Getting this error when trying to dispatch an action to another action. Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

store

```
const configureStore = () => {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        composeWithDevTools(
            applyMiddleware(thunk)
        )
    );
}
```

action

```
export const setLocation = (coords, maxDistance) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return dispatch(setFilteredFacilities(coords, maxDistance))
            .then(() => dispatch({
                type: SET_LOCATION,
                payload: {
                    latitude: coords.latitude,
                    longitude: coords.longitude
                }
            }));
    };
};
```

index.js

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
</Provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dispatching a function and also the result in .then. You cannot dispatch the function.

```
export const setLocation = (coords, maxDistance) => 
{ 
     return (dispatch) =>
     {  
         setFilteredFacilities(coords, maxDistance)
         .then(() =>
               dispatch({ type: SET_LOCATION, 
                   payload: { latitude: coords.latitude, longitude: coords.longitude }
                 })
          ); 
     }  
};
```

Comment: But if the function is a an action, how do I handle that? Because the function is run but not picked up by redux when I don't dispatch it.

Comment: Actions can only be objects. You are dispatching the return from function

Comment: Sorry I feel really stupid regarding dispatching. I want the function that I am running to also be dispatched. So when setLocation is dispatched, setFilteredFacilities should also be dispatched.

    `export const setFilteredFacilities = (yourPosition, maxDistance) => {
        return {
            type: FILITER_FACILITIES,
            payload: {
                facilitiesInRange: facilitiesInRange
            }
        }
    }`